# How to deploy Vite project

Tags: deployment, vite, vercel

Recently I build portfolio using Vite, but I can't deloy on Vercel.
I read some Q & A, but I can't do that.
Please give more details for that.
Thank you.

My vite project is runnig well in local, but I want to see it via cloud.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to explain the method I use (Github with terminal). You can also do it with other services but that goes away from my knowledge.

### Note:

You can use [Github Desktop App](https://desktop.github.com/) in order to make things a little bit more graphical and skip the terminal part. If this sounds better for you then go ahead!

### Things you need:

1. [Git installed](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-Installing-Git) in your machine
2. [Github account](https://github.com/signup?ref_cta=Sign%20up&ref_loc=header%20logged%20out&ref_page=%2F&source=header-home)
3. [Configure Git](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qYoc07Da6kg&ab_channel=CWM-CodingWithMike) so you can access your Github account

---

## Steps:

---

#### Create Github repo

Go to [Github](https://github.com/new) -> Click on [New](https://github.com/new), on top left corner

[image: Github create new repository button]

and [create the repo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u-_uGO95xco&ab_channel=CodingBot). You can leave everything in blank except the repo name. *For this example I will use my username **LeFede** and the repo name will be **test***

[image: Github repo create process]

**IMPORTANT**: I think vercel doesn't support private repos anymore so make sure you create it as **public**

---

#### Some terminal commands you need

Use your terminal to cd into your project's folder. Say it is **C:\Users\yourname\projects\test** then:

```
cd C:\Users\yourname\projects\test
```

Then type the following:

```
git init
git branch -M main
git add .
git commit -m "your commit message"
git push -u origin main
```

After this you are going to have your project uploaded in github

---

#### Go to vercel

and login with Github account. In the [dashboard](https://vercel.com/dashboard) you are going to find the **Add new...** button

[image: Add new button]

Select **Project** option and search your Github repo. Click on **Import**

[image: Vercel search field]

And then **Deploy**

[image: Deploy form]

---

#### Celebrate !

##### Your [App is online!](https://test-seven-azure-85.vercel.app/)

[image: Deployment vite]

Comment: Feel free to ask if you get stucked or if you had any problems!